# Error: avcodec_init();

Tags: init, avcodec

I'll try to compile under Ubuntu 14.04.2 and I get the following error:

```
VideoPlayerPipHd.c: In static member function ‘static void reel::VideoPlayerPipHd::Create()’:
VideoPlayerPipHd.c:792:6: error: ‘avcodec_init’ was not declared in this scope
      avcodec_init -> avcodec_register_all;
      ^
VideoPlayerPipHd.c:793:7: error: ‘av_open_input_file’ was not declared in this scope
   av_open_input_file -> avformat_open_input;
   ^
```

The code is:

```
787     void VideoPlayerPipHd::Create()
788     {
789         if (!instance_)
790         {
791             instance_ = new VideoPlayerPipHd;
792             avcodec_init();
793             avcodec_register_all();
794         }
795     }
```

I tried several things but I am stuck. Could somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are your `#include`s for that file?

Comment: $ grep "#include" VideoPlayerPipHd.c
#include "VideoPlayerPipHd.h"
#include "HdCommChannel.h"
#include "Reel.h" // for Byte
#include <png.h>  // reading png file
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <vdr/thread.h>
#include <vdr/tools.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ffmpeg/swscale.h>
#include <ffmpeg/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the ffmpeg functions are deprecated. See the list here for example:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.8/deprecated.html

For example change `av_open_input_file` to `avformat_open_input`.